# Is Windows 10 HyperV console RDP and can it be changed?

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, cisco-vpn-client

## Background info

A Cisco VPN I'm using disconnects everything on the local network, I need access to my local network as it contains the documentation I use.

### My workaround

- virtual Windows 10 dial-in PC on our Windows 2016 Hyper-V host
- Access the dial-in PC using Hyper-V management console
- Connect the dial-in PC to the Cisco VPN

This works perfectly, the dial-in PC connects to the VPN and on my laptop I have access to our local network.

When I host the same virtual dial-in PC on my Windows 10 Pro laptop the Cisco VPN fails with **"Vpn establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled"** (https://serverfault.com/questions/518771/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-establishment-capability-from-a-remote-desktop-is-disabled)

## Questions

Is the HyperV console of Windows 10 different from the Windows 2016 console ? Is one using RDP while the other is not ?

Is there a way to get this setup to work on Windows 10 ?

I cannot change the VPN settings those are controlled by a third party. They know about, and agree to my workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "enhanced session mode" connections are practically RDP over VMBUS, and the guest system sees them as additional stations (as seen in qwinsta).

Although it doesn't really matter whether they *are* RDP – the problem is that they *aren't local*, i.e. of a different type than the default "console" session.

Disabling enhanced sessions would instead attach you to the *actual* guest console (local video and keyboard), avoiding this problem.

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect for instructions tochange enhanced sessions mode. Connection works find after this change, thanks